# How to wake up early without alarm

Tags: sleeping

The alarm causes people stress. How to avoid waking up early with an alarm? I tried to go to bed earlier but it didn't work.

Comment: This question is off-topic here because it is asking for a mind hack, which is off-topic here.

Comment: A wake-up light (alarm clock that uses a light that slowly increases brightness) is a non-mindhack solution to this.

Comment: @Hobbes Nice, you should post that as an answer!
Dexxrey: Consider adding more to your question. A longer question is less likely to be closed because it looks like you put more thought into it. I don't agree with this, but it happens a lot.

Comment: Also, it's a possible duplicate: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/waking-up-in-the-morning-when-standard-alarms-fail

Comment: most of the answers to that question are not exactly quiet.

Answer (score 3):

My dad taught me this a long time ago. It has never failed me. It does sound strange though. As I'm falling asleep I picture a big faced clock showing the time I want to wake up. At the same time I am repeating the time over and over in my head...8am, 8am...wake up at 8am...I use this method quite often because nothing annoys me more, or sets me up for a bad attitude day is the sound of an alarm. Even waking to the radio gets me going! Good luck!!

Comment: Yas radio always works for me bc you can leave it on for a while and not hit snooze